# get specific column with specific condition from multidimensional array using array function only in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i want to get specific key with specific condition with indexing **0,1,2** from multidimensional array using array function only.

using forloop it is getting but i want it using array function for code optimization

my input code like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [device_token] => 1324
            [device_type] => 0
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [device_token] => 2546
            [device_type] => 1
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [device_token] => 13241
            [device_type] => 0
        )    
    [3] => Array
        (
            [device_token] => 12345
            [device_type] => 1
        )    
)
```

and i want only device_token which have **device_type=0** with following format like :

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 1324,
        [1] => 13241,
)
```

i am trying following code:

```
$ios_token = array_map(function($r) {
            return $r['device_token'];
        }
```

this give me device token of all.

Comment: However a for loop seems adapted ! It is fitted to your issue, why would you think it's not "optimized" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

array_filter should do it for you :

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

```
$ios_token = array_filter($myArray, function($item) {
    return $item['device_type'] == 0;
});
```

It iterates over each value and if the callback function returns true, the current value of the array is returned.

Then you could pass your variable in an array_map function like you did :

```
$ios_token = array_map(function($item){
    return $item['device_token'];
}, $ios_token);
```

And if you want to group everything :

```
$ios_token = array_map(function($item){
    return $item['device_token'];
}, array_filter($myArray, 
    function($item) {
        return $item['device_type'] == 0;
    }
));
```

Comment: This will filter elements with both keys.

Comment: i am trying this but it return entire array which have device_type=0 but iwant only device_token value in format like : Array
    (
        [0] => 1324,
        [1] => 13241,
)

Answer (score 1):

`array_map()` function gives you more possibilities with arrays.
[func_array_map](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_map.asp)

```
function myfunction($v)
{
if ($v['device_type']==0)
   {
        return $v['device_token'];
   }
   return null;
}

$a=array(...) // your array here

print_r(array_values(array_filter(array_map("myfunction",$a))));
```

Comment: this is work but in this index is not getting proper i want index like 0,1,2
but in your code the out put is 0,1,3

Comment: @ChintanMathukiya check now, just saw your indices. added `array_values()` to re map values with new keys

Answer (score 0):

Here you need [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$ios_token = array_reduce(
    $your_array, 
    function($t, $v) {
        if ($v['device_type'] == 0)
            $t[] = $v['device_token'];

        return $t;
    },
    array()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try laconic solution with `array_walk`:

```
// assuming $arr is your main array
$result = [];
array_walk($arr, function($v) use(&$result){
     if ($v['device_type'] == 0) $result[] = $v['device_token'];
});
var_dump($result);
```